# Testing with Selenium in C# - Website which I need to test changes XPath

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to create a testing automation tool in selenium with c# to test the website of my company. Everything works fine, except one thing: everytime when I reload a task on the website (like "create new user"), the XPath of some fields change. The first name field is as example not `"//*[@id=\"0FirstName\"]" anymore, the new xpath would be "//*[@id=\"2FirstName\"]"` and selenium does not recognize that field anymore like before -> program stops working

Is there a way to make a dynamic function to ignore the number before the email?

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"0FirstName\"]")).SendKeys("Selenium");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use XPath [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function like:

   ```
   //*[contains(@id,'FirstName')]
   ```
2. If for some reason it doesn't work, i.e. returns multiple matches you can also implement some form of ends-with() function by using combination of [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath/Functions/substring) and [string-length()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath/Functions/string-length) functions like:

   ```
   //*[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('FirstName')+ 1, string-length(@id))= 'FirstName']
   ```

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your xpath as following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(@id,'FirstName')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use contains()

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id,'FirstName')]")).SendKeys("Selenium");
```